# Alsa, internal mic on macbook works sometimes

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I've had my internal microphone working twice. I'm using simplescreenrecorder, and the internal microphone was working when the input options were set to alsa and [default] default source. So I had it working, and I go click on a couple of things all in the browser, nothing to do with audio input, and I go back to simple screen recorder and my internal mic is not working again.

I wrote down how I had it working which was alsa and default source. I also did the following commands (like last time I got it to work) and it's still not working.

john@john-Ubuntu:~$ killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/* ; rm -r ~/.pulse*; ~/.config/pulse
rm: cannot remove ‘/home/john/.pulse*’: No such file or directory
bash: /home/john/.config/pulse: Is a directory
john@john-Ubuntu:~$ pulseaudio -k

Any idea why it would just start and stop working whenever it wants to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. It looks like it's a bug with Ubuntu probably. I went to system settngs>sound>Input tab> select microphone built in audio, and then over on the right hand side where there is the input volume and the mute button.

Checkbox the mute button, and then un-check it again and that causes the microphone to start working. I hope it works for anyone else having this problem.